# How to break in an MFC/.net application on start

Tags: .net, debugging, mfc, c++-cli

I've got an old MFC application that uses .net dlls and cpp/cli dlls.

I get this error on start up. Access Violation.

```
'app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'app.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120_clr0400.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown at 0x000007FEFD07A06D (KernelBase.dll) in app.exe: 0x04242420 (parameters: 0x0000000031415927, 0x000007FEEF8F0000, 0x00000000001EE9B0).
Exception thrown at 0x000007FEF72BD95C (mscoreei.dll) in app.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

This is the only resolved part of the call stack.

```
mscoreei.dll!CLRUEFManager::AddUnhandledExceptionFilterInternal(long (*)(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *),int) Unknown
```

So I'm wondering if anyone has seen this?
How can I break in the code MFC code earlier than `InitInstance()`

Comment: Launch the application by invoking the *"Step into"* debugger command (mapped to [F11] when using the default VS6 C++ keyboard shortcuts).

Comment: Wow, that worked. Add the answer and I'll accept it.